# Clean fridge shelves which can't be removed?

Tags: food-safety

What's the best way to clean out the parts of a fridge that can't be removed? I found that on my fridge, for whatever reason, some shelves on the inside of the door can't be taken out.  Is there a cleaner that can be used that's food safe that I can use in the fridge without washing it off?

Comment: I use vodka for the parts of the fridge I cannot easily reach, but it's not a "spray on and forget" solution: you still have to wipe it off afterwards, so this is just a comment.  If this is what you need, let me know and I"ll convert it to an answer...  **;-)**

Comment: Find the manufacturers manual on-line, I doubt shelves can't be removed, just tricky :-)

Answer (score 3):

You have to wash cleaners off, there's no other way to remove the dirt. The gunk is not going to magically evaporate, you will have to wipe. If your fridge is really dirty then I suggest a tub of soapy (dish soap) water, a sponge to clean and wipe, and a towel to dry. If it's not that bad then a kitchen safe spray cleaner and a sponge or paper towels will do fine. A pair of rubber kitchen gloves would be a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

There are specialized "fridge cleaners" in the drugstore, but if you take a look at the ingredients list, you'll find out that you are paying lots of money for a small amount of alcohol and tensides.

You can follow GdD's advice and use soap, then wash it off, then wipe it dry Other cleaners such as window cleaner can also be used, they are safe enough - gulping them down won't be pleasant, but if small amounts come in contact with food, nothing will happen. The other way is to use alcohol and sponge it off, without washing it off with water afterwards. It will evaporate on its own.

Any tenside based cleaner should be washed off, even if the manufacturer was brazen enough to say that there is no need for it. Else you are left with an invisible tenside film on the fridge wall which catches and holds fast to any piece of dirt flying around.

Answer (score 0):

I try to clean shelves regularly so the sludge doesn't get too thick, but if it did get thick, I would probably break out the steam cleaner. It's great for cutting through thick dried-on sludge. I would be careful of any glass, however, because the temperature shock might break it (most glass shelves are removable, though).

Answer (score 0):

Bleach (1-10% depending how bad the fridge is) water, rag or sponge, wipe clean, wipe off/dry, rinse with plain water, wipe clean/dry. Ideally park all the food in a cooler so you can air the fridge out throughly after cleaning.